# column data to rows with given condition using pandas library

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am currently working on python as I am new to it. I have a data frame in which two columns exists as given below.

```
id   | parent
1    | A
2    | B
3    | C
4    | A
5    | A
6    | C
```

And required output was like:

```
id   | parent | child
1    | A      | NaN
2    | B      | NaN
3    | C      | NaN
4    | A      | NaN
5    | A      | NaN
6    | C      | NaN
NaN  | A      | 1 ; 4 ; 5
NaN  | B      | 2 
NaN  | C      | 3 ; 6
```

I have used following code:

> print (df.fillna(['id']))
>   print(df.parent_page_id.unique())

I need help to retrieve output like above table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `groupby` on 'parent' column, then use `apply` to build 'child', finally `concat` them.

```
t = df.groupby('parent')['id'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x.astype(str)))
t = pd.DataFrame(t).reset_index()
t.columns = ['parent', 'child']
pd.concat([df, t])
```

Output:

```
Out[74]:
   child   id parent
0    NaN  1.0      A
1    NaN  2.0      B
2    NaN  3.0      C
3    NaN  4.0      A
4    NaN  5.0      A
5    NaN  6.0      C
0  1;4;5  NaN      A
1      2  NaN      B
2    3;6  NaN      C
```

Comment: Thanks sir for help

Comment: @Sunil Welcome to SO. In SO, if a answer solve one's problem, he can vote up or accept answer to reward answerer.

Answer (score 1):

Use groupby to concat child ids for parents and then concat the parent-child df to original df.

```
df_parent_kids = df.astype(str).groupby('parent')['id']\
                    .agg(lambda x: ' ; '.join(x)).reset_index().rename(columns={'id':'child'})
pd.concat([df,df_parent_kids])[['id','parent','child']]

Out[598]: 
    id parent      child
0  1.0      A        NaN
1  2.0      B        NaN
2  3.0      C        NaN
3  4.0      A        NaN
4  5.0      A        NaN
5  6.0      C        NaN
0  NaN      A  1 ; 4 ; 5
1  NaN      B          2
2  NaN      C      3 ; 6
```